# Vue.js can't divide code into loadable small chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, code-splitting

#### My problem:

I can't split `vue.js` code into chunks, I have tried a lot of examples from tutorials. When I am trying to not load `vue component` with app and split it, for example, with `v-if="show_component"`, got an error `component included, but not used`. I don't know how to split code and use `components`, when they needed. **In practice**, there are no any working examples.

#### Example of the problem with `vue-js-modal`:

Can't divide modals into loadable chunks.
I need to load modals only when they triggered to open. It will shrink first page load size. But this option is impossible. Here is my modals structure:

> ***/src/components/Modals/ExampleModal.vue***

```
<template>
    <modal name="examplemodal" class="examplemodal-modal" :adaptive="true" :max-width="450">
        <div class="header row">
            <h3>Title is here</h3>
            <v-icon name="times" />
        </div>

        <div class="content col">
            <p>
                <b>Some content</b>
                <br /><br />
                More text here...
            </p>
        </div>
    </modal>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.examplemodal-modal {
    background: rgba(9, 15, 30, 0.3);

    .vm--modal {
        //  I got here a lot of styles in modals
    }
}
</style>
```

> ***/src/main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon';
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';

Vue.component('v-icon', Icon);
 /* Tried to make loadable modals, divided to chunks */
Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true, injectModalsContainer: true });

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

> ***/src/App.vue***

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <modals-container />

                <button class="btn green" @click="showModal">
            Show modal
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ExampleModal from './components/ExampleModal.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
        methods: {
            showModal() { this.$modal.show(ExampleModal ) } // Shows empty modal
        }
};
</script>
```

Modal still don't divided into loadable chunks.
If you got any ideas, please, help me.

#### Version of `vue-js-modal`:

^2.0.0-rc.3

> I have checked stackoverflow for solutions and 100% sure that this issue is not not related to my code.

Comment: What bundler do you use? Webpack? Parcel?

Comment: I am using Webpack

Answer (score 0):

Webpack has an optimization
[Webpzck optimization](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#root)

Here is en example:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a test folder, you should set

```
test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
```

or your tests can't bundle and run.

Comment: WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings
Asset size limitexceed the recommended limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  js/chunk-vendors.eeb78322.js (322 KiB)
entrypoint size limit: asset size exceeds the recomme                                                                                                           nded (244 KiB).
Entrypoints:
  app (414 KiB)
      css/chunk-vendors.cbfdb985.css
      js/chunk-vendors.eeb78322.js
      css/app.a29817c4.css
      js/app.2ccfe5c8.js

Comment: My vue.config.js is empty

Comment: hm, ...ok, so where you had added this optimization property?

Comment: inside webpack config

Comment: Can you make a screen of your project structure? Do you have a use vue-cli for creating it?

Comment: yes, can I send you screenshot and chat you somewhere in vk.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219743/discussion-between-you-retrded-community-and-valerii-voronkov).